# Outlook append rule then run script and save attachments to folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I use this script in rules

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "c:\temp\"

    MkDir itm.Parent, saveFolder ' here creating folder if not exist

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & itm.Parent & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

But problems is that all atachments saving into INBOX called folder but not in folder in which mail was moved.

So how to get folder name in which email was moved by the rule?

So now is saving in `c:\temp\Inbox` but must be in `c:\temp\Unfiled` or if moved folder is subfolder so must be `c:\temp\Folder\Unfiled`

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is you are asking the rule the move the MailItem and the script to save the attachments.  From your description, I deduce Outlook runs the script before the rule moves the MailItem.  This is not what the Rule Wizard says is to happen but the symptoms do not match what the Rule Wizard says.

The disc folder address is `saveFolder & "\" & itm.Parent & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName`.  Before the MailItem is moved `itm.Parent` is “Inbox”.  Only after the move would `itm.Parent` be “Unfiled”.

Your choices include:

1. Having the script save attachments and move the email so you control the sequence.
2. Save the attachments to `saveFolder & "\Unfiled\" & objAtt.DisplayName`